# Kaspersky is blocking the SOAP service response

Tags: java, web-services, soap, glassfish

In my desktop application i have a reference to a SOAP web service. The service is deployed on Glassfish server 3.0 and is mainly used to send byte arrays to client that form a pdf file. The service method sends 1 file at a time.

However, the problem is that some of the files never get transferred to the client unless the client machine pauses Kaspersky protection. I have tried adding my application to kaspersky's trusted applications but it doesn't help.

Has anyone had similar issues? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure exclusions in Kaspersky Anti-Virus.
You can follow below steps:
1) click Settings.
2) In the Settings window, go to the Protection Center section and select Web Anti-Virus.
3) In the Web Anti-Virus settings window, click Advanced Settings.
4) In the window Advanced settings of Web Anti-Virus, you can modify the following parameters:
   Configure Kaspersky URL Advisor --> On all websites except those specified

Here configure the URL of WSDL of your soap service.

But this approach you can use only for your machine  ;-)
Quoted from [Link](http://support.kaspersky.com/11236#block4).